# how to implement String value to date formate

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the php code to get string $date from textbox 
Now how can i

(1)convert the string in to the date formate variable
(2)How to chech $date is Date Variable

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
  $date = new DateTime($textbox->getValue());
} cath (Exception $e) {
  $errors[] = 'Invald date format, please use Y-m-d H:i:s';
}


if (!($date instanceof DateTime)) {
   echo 'Variable $date is not DateTime object!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function getTime($date) {
    $timestamp = strtotime((string)$date);
    return date("m-d-Y H:i:s", $timestamp);
}
```